# How to hide all the form fields when page loads and enable when selected from drop-down

Tags: html, forms

I am trying to display a text field on selecting the different values from a combo box option

html file

```
<select id="topic_type" onchange="func_type()">
<option id="n" selected>N</option>
<option id="d"> D</option>
<option id="o">O</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
function func_type() 
 {
var elem = document.getElementById("topic_type");

if(elem.value == "D") 
{
    document.getElementById("form_d").style.display= "block";
    document.getElementById("form_o").style.display= "none"; 
} 
else if(elem.value == "O")
{
    document.getElementById("form_o").style.display= "block";
    document.getElementById("form_d").style.display= "none";
}
}
</script>
```

In this when i load the page the default value is *n* and all the fields of *form_d* and *form_o* are displayed at the same time. When i change the value in the drop-down some field is visible as required.

My problem is when the page is loaded i want that all the form field should be hidden.
How can i do it

thanks in advance.

Comment: If your drop down is out of this two forms, just add style="display:none;" to both forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this condition to your script

```
else if(elem.value == "N")
{
    document.getElementById("form_o").style.display= "none";
    document.getElementById("form_d").style.display= "none";
}
```

and call `func_type()` just before end `</script>` tag

http://jsfiddle.net/smknQ/

Answer (score 1):

```
You can hide the required elements on jQuery document ready function.

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#idoftheelement").hide();

});
```